# Why is PHP $_FILES always null

Tags: php

I have HTML like

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I keep getting `null` for `$_FILES` why is that?

Comment: Show php code .. Did you tried `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: Does the uploaded file have an extension? 

`On windows XP, SP2, Explorer at times fails to upload files without extensions. $_FILES array is null in that case. Microsoft says its a security feature(!) The only solution we could comeup is to enforce uploaded file to have an extention.`

Comment: @Shakti Singh, yes I did that, any problems with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php print_r($_FILES);?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Check the code above:

it should produce the following output:

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => ezwebin_userguide.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php1485.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1073054
        )

)
```

Answer (score 10):

In the form section make sure you have this code: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing more specific data?
Ex:

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["error"]
```

Or

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

file_uploads might be off in php.ini. Try this script:

```
<?php
echo 'file_uploads: '. ini_get('file_uploads'). '<br />';
echo 'upload_tmp_dir: '. ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'). '<br />';
echo 'upload_max_filesize: '. ini_get('upload_max_filesize'). '<br />';
echo 'max_file_uploads: '. ini_get('max_file_uploads'). '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: I get something like "file_uploads: 1
upload_tmp_dir: 
upload_max_filesize: 10M
max_file_uploads: 20" `upload_tmp_dir` is empty, shld I set it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and none of theme was my error. Check in your .htaccess file, if you got one, if "MultiViews" are enabled. I had to disable them.